# How does awaitMessages work in Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using Discord.JS v12.0.0

I recently heard of `awaitMessages` and read a bit about it but I don't really understand it well. I would really appreciate if someone could give some examples of `awaitMessages` or maybe show me how it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`.awaitMessages()` is similar to using `.createMessageCollector()`, except it's Promise based, meaning you can't do anything untill the Promise is rejected or resolved.

You can find an example and a more detailed explanation [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages) and [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/), [`awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

> Similar to createMessageCollector but in promise form. Resolves with a collection of messages that pass the specified filter.

Example from docs:

> ```js
> // Await !vote messages
> const filter = m => m.content.startsWith('!vote');
> // Errors: ['time'] treats ending because of the time limit as an error
> channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 4, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
>   .then(collected => console.log(collected.size))
>   .catch(collected => console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 
> voted.`));
> ```

Some other examples such as Q&A features can be found in the [official discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages)